# Why is the date/timestamp difference always NULL?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, cursor

I just coded this way:

```
Cursor cursor;
String sql = "SELECT l.acao, SUM(strftime('%s',l.data_fim) - strftime('%s',l.data_inicio)) AS total_time," +
             "FROM logs AS l " +
             "WHERE l.data_fim IS NOT NULL " +
             "GROUP BY l.acao";
```

I need to sum the seconds between two dates and I named this sum `total_time`. But when I try to get the result of `total_time` it always returns `null`, see next code:

```
String totalTimeInSeconds = (String) cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("total_time"));
```

When I put this same query in SqlLiteStudio it works perfectly. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the value in the cursor actually is NULL.

This can happen only when the original date values are not in one of the [supported date formats](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#datetime). You have to change your database.

Comment: Man, i guess thats it, cuz the field in the table is datetime and the value are stored as 'dd/mm/yyyy' format, ill try to store in american format to see. Thanks

Comment: i recorded the date in american format and worked perfectly, thanks more one time.

Comment: If the answer helped you, please [accept it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Answer (score 0):

instead of using `cursor.getColumnIndex()`, you can enter the exact index in it. In your case the total_time index is 1. Ex : `cursor.getString(1)` or `cursor.getInt(1)`

Comment: thanks for answer me, but i tried this, using breakpoint i can see the column but the value is always null, i think is something when i put some functions in select section